# How to remove / rebuild product cache image with the help of product id?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media-images

I want to remove the particular product image from cache folder at the time of product edit from admin.

I need to change the product image when product getting edit and its working fine.

Now at that time I also want to remove old product image from Cache with the help of product id.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not try this code by my own

You can try below code for flush single product Imgae,

please try and let me know if its not work

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache('CATALOG_PRODUCT_' . $the_product_id);
```